# Jquery in wordpress has not style or js

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu

I would add this menu (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/05/horizontal-drop-down-menu/) to a specific page in WordPress. I created menudropdown.html and I called in content_page with "if (is_page ()). "

All right, the html appears in page I chose, the problem is has not style or js functionality. That is just pure html (nested lists) appears me but neither the style nor the js menu. Add the css in the css theme folder to use and also js in js folder, but do not know if I'm doing something wrong or missing something to me that if I run the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to register and enque the stylesheet and javascript in your theme's functions.php file.

The process for scripts and stylesheets is essentially the same. You have wp_register_script and wp_register_style to set them up, then wp_enqueue_script and wp_enqueue_style to load them.

Examples can be found on registering scripts on the codex pages for these:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

And to enqueue...

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script